# remote_api does not work with python 2.7.9

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

With python 2.7.9 I got the following Traceback. Do we get a new GAE-Release, or do I have to 
go back with Python.

```
    remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteDatastore(None, '/????_remote', auth_func, h
ost)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remo
te_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 874, in ConfigureRemoteApi
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remo
te_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 569, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
    response = server.Send(path, payload=None, **urlargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pengine_rpc.py", line 420, in Send
    self._Authenticate()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pengine_rpc.py", line 561, in _Authenticate
    super(HttpRpcServer, self)._Authenticate()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pengine_rpc.py", line 311, in _Authenticate
    auth_token = self._GetAuthToken(credentials[0], credentials[1])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pengine_rpc.py", line 250, in _GetAuthToken
    response = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1242, in https_open
    context=self._context)
TypeError: do_open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug with 2.7.9. There's workaround on the bug, if you're willing to edit a file in the SDK. Otherwise, revert to a prior version of Python until there's an official fix.

see https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11536